stack won't show full list in c# when I try to add inputs
Today I was learning about different types of data structures and I was trying to make a program that pops an element of a stack when prompted. However when I added a new text and input after the for loop, it only prints the last part of the stack.
Additionally I get this result when I type either the "y" or "n" prompt in for input:
System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1[System.String]
I also tried breaking my code down into pieces to try and see where the problem begins and I found that the write line and input after the for loop cause the issue with the stack now showing fully.
Also Here is the code in it's entirety:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Stack<string> wordActions = new Stack<string>();
        wordActions.Push("resized text to 100");
        wordActions.Push("recoloured text to red");
        wordActions.Push("changed font to Courier New");
        wordActions.Push("aligned text to center");
        wordActions.Push("changed text to italic type");
        
        foreach (string wordAction in wordActions) {
            Console.WriteLine(wordAction);
            
            Console.WriteLine("would you like to undo the last action? type y for yes and n for no");
            string userInput =Console.ReadLine();
            
            if (userInput == "y" | (userInput == "Y")) {
                wordActions.Pop();
                Console.WriteLine($"you have undone the last action which was CHANGED TEXT TO ITALIC TYPE. \nhere is your list of commands now:");
                Console.WriteLine(wordActions);
            }
            
            else if (userInput == "n" | (userInput == "N")) {
                Console.WriteLine("No problem your list of actions is still as follows:");
                Console.WriteLine(wordActions);
            }
            
            System.Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}

Thank you for answers in advance!


System.Environment.Exit(0); ends the program immediately. 2. Console.WriteLine(wordActions); is printing what it should. Why am I getting System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] instead of the list's contents?


Change Console.WriteLine(wordActions); to e.g. Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", wordActions));

Console.WriteLine(wordActions);

is short for
Console.WriteLine(wordActions.ToString());

.ToString() simply prints the type name, i.e. "System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1[System.String]", for most types. If you want the actual content of the list you need to convert it to a string yourself. For example:
foreach(var word in wordActions){
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}

Or you can use the built in function to construct one large string:
Console.WriteLine(string.join(Environment.NewLine, wordActions))

Also, your outer loop is kind of weird, since you are both looping over the items, and accepting commands. These should probably be separate loops. A simple command menu would look something like:
while(true){
    // print possible inputs
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    switch(userInput){
        case "push" :
            wordActions.Push(Console.ReadLine());
        break;
        case "pop":
          Console.WriteLine(wordActions.Pop());
        break;
        case "print":
          Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, wordActions));
        break;
        case "quit":
          return;
       default:
           Console.WriteLine("Unrecognized command");
          

